# how to get key from value in hash table

Tags: c#

I have hashtable with key and values and in my code I am iterating hashtable through values like below :

```
foreach (Object clientObject in ClientList.Values)
{
    // code to perform operation based on value
    ......
}
```

Where ClientList is hashtable.
Now I want to get key of perticualar value from hashtable in my code. is there any way to achieve that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to iterate through the table in this way:

```
        Hashtable clientList = new Hashtable();

        foreach (DictionaryEntry dictionaryEntry in clientList)
        {
            // work with value.
            Debug.Print(dictionaryEntry.Value.ToString());

            // work with key.
            Debug.Print(dictionaryEntry.Key.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, I think your way of iteration is better to solve my problem.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the list of `keys` that have a certain value, using LINQ (.NET >= 3.5)

```
object searchedValue = something;

IEnumerable<object> keys = ClientList.Cast<DictionaryEntry>().Where(p => ClientList.Values == searchedValue).Select(p => p.Key);
```

This probably isn't what you *wanted*, but it's what you *asked*.

(the code means: take all the elements of `ClientList` (each element is a "tuple" of key and value) and search the one(s) that has the value equal to the searched value. Take the keys of those elements.

Comment: Thanks. We can get key using linq as like your code. but better I iterate hashtable like way mentioned by Fischermaen.

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible to get the Key by using the value.

**One of the reason is key are unique and Value are not unique in the HashTable.**

You can use @Fischermaen way to read the value.